# Why isn't _main always the first procedure?

Tags: c, assembly, compilation, arm

I compiled curl on my M1 (i.e. ARM) Mac running macOS 13.2.1 with `Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)` and disassembled the resulting executable with

```bash
objdump -D --macho ./src/curl
```

and the first lines I see are

```
/Users/space/code/third-party/curl/src/curl:
(__TEXT,__text) section
_slist_wc_append:
100003924:      ff c3 00 d1     sub     sp, sp, #48
100003928:      fd 7b 02 a9     stp     x29, x30, [sp, #32]
10000392c:      fd 83 00 91     add     x29, sp, #32
100003930:      e0 0b 00 f9     str     x0, [sp, #16]
100003934:      e1 07 00 f9     str     x1, [sp, #8]
100003938:      e1 07 40 f9     ldr     x1, [sp, #8]
10000393c:      00 00 80 d2     mov     x0, #0
100003940:      8e 66 02 94     bl      _curl_slist_append
[...]
```

`_main` doesn't appear until byte `1000147b4` (line 17388 in the disassembly). `slist_wc_append()` has to do with curl's `--libcurl` argument which causes it to also generate C code that makes the same network request it makes and save it to a file, why is it the first procedure in the executable?

I expected that executables would always start executing from the first instruction and that it would be the first instruction from `_main`. I disassembled CPython and Bash and they do. Does the OS look for the location of `_main` in the symbol table and set the stack pointer to that before executing? I've seen that it's possible to tell the assembler to use a different name instead of `_main` with `.global _different_name`. Is curl doing something special before calling `_main`?

Comment: Most formats have a header with a field that specifies the entry point. It is typically not the first instruction. Also, if you link with the C library as curl likely does, the process doesn't even start at `main` but in the C library (usually `_start`) which then calls your `main`. The OS doesn't do symbol lookup, it just uses the address in the header field that the linker fills in (which indeed can use a different symbol if you tell it to).

Comment: A symbol table is only available at runtime in debug versions.

Comment: Note that if TLS(Thread Local Storage) Callback is specified, it's executed before the entry point.

Answer (score 3):

On macOS, the `eip` field of a Mach-O file is used to set the instruction pointer.

https://github.com/corkami/pics/blob/master/binary/macho101/macho101-64.pdf

ELF on Linux has a similar `e_entry` field

https://github.com/corkami/pics/blob/master/binary/elf101/elf101-64.pdf

Comment: For your reference, for PE headers(Windows), specify the entry point as `AddressOfEntryPoint` in the Optional headers.

Comment: Strictly speaking the doesn’t answer my why question.

Comment: @BorisVerkhovskiy Note that `_main` isn't even the first thing that executes of your binary.  There's usually some sort of startup code before that.  But even that doesn't have to be the first thing in the binary, making it much easier to lay out the code.

Answer (score 3):

The OS doesn't follow the standard calling convention when transferring control to the program entry point.  The OS doesn't know what programming language the program uses (for, say, `main` or anything else).  So, the OS simply transfers control to the program entry point, and lets that provide the software in machine code to invoke `main` or whatever is appropriate for the program.

Further, the program entry point is not a function — that is, it is not "called" by the OS in the classic sense of functions in programming languages, and the program entry point cannot "return" to its caller (the OS) as there is none in that same classic sense — so the program entry point is somewhat special, and its primary purpose is to start normal function calling, i.e. with `main`, or whatever is appropriate for the programming language used at the beginning of the program.

The symbol `_start` is the common name for the entry point, and its job it to invoke `main` as a function and, if necessary, terminate the executable (via some system call) should the function `main` return.

> Why isn't _main always the first procedure?

It can be the first procedure/function but probably isn't due to other setup requirements before invoking `main`.  In any case `_start` isn't really a procedure so simply cannot qualify as the first procedure/function, even if it is the first code to run.

Comment: On Darwin (i.e. my ARM macOS system) it’s called `_main`, not `_start`. See https://github.com/below/HelloSilicon#hello-world

Comment: @BorisVerkhovskiy: `_main` may be the first routine you usually see, but the actual first routine of typical user processes is `_start`. `_start` is a special routine that sets up the program’s environment and then calls `_main`. It is linked in by default.

Answer (score 3):

> Why isn't _main always the first procedure?

There is no reason `_main` needs to be the first symbol in an executable file or the first symbol in the text (code) section of an executable file. The program loader knows where to start a program by information in the program file that specifies its start address, not by picking the first symbol in the program or a section of it.

> `slist_wc_append()` … why is it the first procedure in the executable?

Most likely because it happened to be the first symbol in the text section of its object module and its object module was the first one listed in the link command. Which routine is first in the text section is largely unimportant.

> I expected that executables would always start executing from the first instruction and that it would be the first instruction from `_main`.

Why did you expect this? Is there some documentation that tells you to expect this?

The following is written primarily for macOS and similar Unix systems.

When the system is starting a new program, often because one of the `exec` family of routines was called to execute a program, the program loader sets up the initial environment for the program. Among the things it does is read or map parts of the executable file into memory and transfer program control to the start address of the program. The start address is recorded in a particular place in the executable file. By default, the linker (the `ld` command) sets the start address to the value of the symbol  `_start` (on Linux and macOS, and some other systems).  On Linux, `readelf -a /bin/ls` and look for the `Entry point address` to see that piece of metadata.

The code for the `_start` routine is provided by a default library that is linked into a program. That default library may vary depending on which programming language is specified when compiling and linking the program, but is often called the CRT startup code (C RunTime). The C version of the `_start` routine sets up the C environment and then calls `_main`. The C++ version sets up the C++ environment and then calls the C++ `main` routine.

> I've seen that it's possible to tell the assembler to use a different name instead of `_main` with `.global _different_name`.

`.global` just says to make a name known outside the current assembly file, not to make it the start routine.

To set a different start routine, you use the `-e name` switch with the linker. If you set it to `_main`, your program will likely not work, because a C program usually needs the initialization done by `_start` to function correctly.

(In macOS at least, the `_start` routine is normally in a shared library that is not linked into a program until it is loaded, so it will not appear in a disassembly of your executable file.)

Answer (score 2):

Starting the program is much more complicated. OS is loading the file into the memory, does many other things (like relocating the addresses, assuring that dynamically loaded libraries will not have any address conflicts etc etc) and eventually passes the control to your program. But it is not the `main` function; it is usually something else and is called startup code. It prepares the environment, initializes variables and does all the necessary things required to call the `main` function which is the startup point of your program.